# laravel 5: Where define global Vars?

Tags: php, constants, laravel-5

In the old laravel 4 Code we use an constants.php to define global vars.

What is the best practices to use define vars in Laravel 5?

We wouldn't store it in the .env file or the routes.php

Comment: "variables" - "constants" Those names don't ring any bells for you? You should not use globals in any way. For application "constants" you should use `Config`. For class constants you should use class constants.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv You say "You should not use globals in any way" yet right after that you say "you should use Config". Please explain how those two differ??

Comment: `Config` is used for _constants_, not _variables_. Globals, be them variables or carefully used as constants are bad. Global variables are just bad practice. For constants there are better ways as I said - `Config`.

Comment: I mean how is the stuff wrapped in a class called `Config` suddenly less global? Same problems different name...

Comment: "You should not use globals in any way" aggree @SergiuParaschiv, but i rewrite old code.

Comment: @PeeHaa it's different because you don't use it for global variables. Global variables are bad because in the long run it becomes harder to maintain sane application logic when you don't know who or what is changing them. Global _constants_ on the other hand are easier to manage because you cannot change them thus don't have to follow business logic to find out who or what is changing them. The advantage of `Config` over plain globals (we're only talking about constants here) is that you have an acceptable way of managing dependencies using the built-in dependency injector.

Comment: Dependencies? I thought we were talking about constants here? Also you still haven't answered my question? How is the Config thing not global?

Comment: @MartinSchäpker if you are rewriting then you should not be constrained to keeping a 1:1 codebase. You should refactor those globals into a more manageable dependency, using the provider API and the dependency injector.

Comment: @PeeHaa I read my previous comments and cannot find the place where I said `Config` was _not_ global. Furthermore in my previous reply I explained what are the benefits `Config` offers over plain globals - the dependency injector.

Comment: You started by saying "You should not use globals in any way" so I assumed your solution would not actually involve globals.

Comment: @PeeHaa I did not offer a solution. I would have posted an answer if I did that. I do realize that I should have written "You should not use globals (`global $myVar` or `$GLOBALS['myVar']`)...".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just want to improve a little bit @Adam's answer. Suppose an online shopping cart.  Then, you want a global var to store the `currency symbol` in order to be displayed at views. Because this value can be changed across the time, you can specify it at `App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider` like so:

```
public function register()
{
    $currency = 'whatever you want';

    config([
        'currency' => $currency
    ]);
}
```

The `$currency = config('currency')` var is global for use at entire application even the request is not yet arrived at controllers (you can read more about [middleware classes](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware)).

If you definitively want to use constanst (values never change) you could consider set the values at config files direclty as below:

```
# create a new config file config/customs.php 

# like content, you could start with:
return  [
    'currency' => '$'
];
```

Finally, you grap the value in your app with `config('customs.currency')`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what sort of variables you are trying to store. If they are related to the model they should be stored in the model, if they are related to the environment they should be stored in .env. What sort of variables are you trying to store?

Comment: We have one file in the config/ folder that need this global Vars, if we store it to the related model we got an Fatal Error because \Eloquent not available. I think thats broken by Concept.

Comment: What sort of variables are you trying to store?

Comment: e.g.:  
define('COUNTRY_ID_AU' ,  36);

Comment: You could create a configuration file called countries, that would have an array with the country shortcode as the key and id as the value?